# unable to assign Blob variable that is returned by EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String) method

Tags: apex, encodingutil, blob.topdf

Unable to assign `Blob` variable that is returned by `EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String)` method

```
Blob k = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature__c); 
Attachment record = new Attachment(ParentId = call.Id, Name=call.name+'.pdf',  Body = Blob.toPDF(k));
insert record;
```

Throws error :

> Variable does not exist: Blob at line 18 column 112

Comment: yes these 2 question address to same requirement, but here i'm concerned about return type of EncodingUtil.base64Decode() method in Blob variable, in the previous question i was not traversing using this method, rather using <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,kjhhj="/> html tag. These 2 questions is of the same problem having 2 different solution approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do the below

```
Blob k = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature__c); 
 Attachment record = new Attachment(ParentId = call.Id, Name=call.name+'.pdf',  Body = k,ContentType='application/pdf');
 insert record;
```

Comment: thansk,i just tried out this solution, pdf gets generated but the content is not supporting, Failed to load PDF document. previously i was using 
Attachment record = new Attachment(ParentId = call.Id, Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature__c), ContentType = 'image/jpeg'); but now i want to include some texts also call.account__r.name thats why i need this to be pdf, but i also need encoded signature images along with it

Comment: So saikat ,The way to do this is change the content type to image itself and then use the following code in your vf  <apex:image url="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!Attach}" height="100px"
            width="200px" />/// Code for controller public NoteAndAttachment Attach {get;set;}